# Modify Input layer of Keras Model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, shapes

I've a pretrained network. I want read that model and change the shape of input layer. I've tried with following code:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
print(tf.version.VERSION)
```

*2.4.1*

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/drive", force_remount=True )
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("/content/drive/My Drive/NonQuantRelu.h5")
new_model.summary()
```

*Model: "functional_1"*

*Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param   #*

*Input (InputLayer)           [(**None**, 108, 1)]          0*

*ConvL1_Filters (Conv1D)      (None, 98, 24)            264*

I really don't want the **None** in the InputLayer, so I've tried to:

```
new_input_layer = keras.Input(batch_size=1, shape=(108,1),name="Input",dtype="float32",ragged=False,sparse=False)
new_input_layer.shape
```

TensorShape([**1**, 108, 1])

```
new_model.layers[0] = new_input_layer
new_model.summary()
```

*Model: "functional_1"*

*Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param   #*

*Input (InputLayer)           [(**None**, 108, 1)]          0*

*ConvL1_Filters (Conv1D)      (None, 98, 24)            264*

Why Input layer is not changed?
Thank to everyone

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate your issue using `vgg16` network.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/vgg16.h5')
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
2.4.1
Drive already mounted at /content/drive/; to attempt to forcibly remount, call drive.mount("/content/drive/", force_remount=True).

Model: "vgg16"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
=================================================================
Total params: 14,714,688
Trainable params: 14,714,688
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

To remove first layer of the network, use [pop](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#pop) as shown below

```
 model._layers.pop(0)
```

To add new input layer, you can run code as shown below

```
new_input_layer = tf.keras.Input(batch_size= 32, shape=(224,224,3))
new_output_layer = model(new_input_layer)
new_model = tf.keras.Model(new_input_layer, new_output_layer)
new_model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(32, 224, 224, 3)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
vgg16 (Functional)           (None, 7, 7, 512)         14714688  
=================================================================
Total params: 14,714,688
Trainable params: 14,714,688
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

You can use `get_layer` to retrieve a layer. Here to get `vgg16 (Functional)` layer (*i.e. indexed at 1 in the new_model*) details, you can run code as shown below

```
new_model.get_layer(index=1).summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "vgg16"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
=================================================================
Total params: 14,714,688
Trainable params: 14,714,688
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```